# Select options dropdown validation inside form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

We are trying add to validation for Select options inside form,  its working fine for 1st dropdown field, but validation not working for **2nd dropdown** & **3rd multi select checkbox fields**.

means when we click on submit button ,  form is submitting and values are saving in database without caring about 2nd and 3rd fields.

[image]

**php**

```
<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="update.php" id="" onsubmit="return validate(); ">

        Designer : 
          <select onchange="getOrderDetail(event);" name="designer_id" id="designer_id" required>
            <option value="">Select Designer</option>
                  <?php 
                       while($data = $stmt->fetch())  
                        { 
                           if($data['type']=="admin")continue;
                  ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['userID'];?>">
                  <?php 
                     echo $data['name'];
                  ?>
            </option>
                  <?php } ?>
          </select>

      Order : 


        <div id="ordernumbers">
          <select name="designerorder_id" id="designerorder_id" required>
            <option>Select Order</option>
          </select>
          </div>      

      Product

        <div id="productnumbers" name="dproduct_id" id="dproduct_id" required>
          <select id="mySelect" >
            <option>Select Products</option>
          </select>

        </div>
```

**script**

```
function validate()
{

 var error="";

 var designer_id = document.getElementById( "designer_id" );
 if( designer_id.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Designer";
  document.getElementById( "error_para1" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }

 var error="";
 var designerorder_id = document.getElementById( "designerorder_id" );
 if( designerorder_id.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Order";
  document.getElementById( "error_para2" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }


 var error="";
 var dproduct_id = document.getElementById( "dproduct_id" );

 if( dproduct_id.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Product";
  document.getElementById( "error_para3" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }

}

function getOrderDetail(e)
  {
    var designerId=e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;    
    var url="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/designerpaidstatus.php?designer_id="+designerId+"&opration=2";
       var request = jQuery.ajax( {
                url: url ,
                type: 'POST',                      
            } );

            request.done( function (result)
            {  
              document.getElementById('ordernumbers').innerHTML =result;

            } );
            request.fail( function ( error )
            {
                console.dir(error);             
            } );
     }
  function getProductDetail(e)
  {    
    var productId = $("#dproductselect option:selected").attr("class");  
    var finalstrig=productId.split(",");

    var select='';
    select+='<select class="test" multiple="multiple" name="dproduct_ids" id="dproduct_ids">';

    for(i=0;i<finalstrig.length;i++)
    {
      if(finalstrig[i]!=0)
      {
        select +='<option value="'+finalstrig[i]+'">'+finalstrig[i]+'</option>';
      }
    }
    select +='</select>';   
    document.getElementById('productnumbers').innerHTML =select;
    (function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.test').fSelect();
    });
})(jQuery);

  }

$(function(){
  $("#button_reset").click(function() { 
    $("#productnumbers").html('<select id="mySelect"><option>Select Products</option></select>');
  });
});
```

**Edit** - **Designerpaidstatus.php**

```
$htmltext='';   
    $htmltext="<select id='dproductselect' name='designerorder_id' onchange='getProductDetail(this.value)'><option value=''>Select Order</option>";
    foreach ($order as $orderData)  
    {
        $orderitems=$orderData['dproduct_id'];

            $finalValue=$orderData->getIncrementId()."-".$orderitemsarray[$k];
            $htmltext=$htmltext.'<option class="'.$orderitems.'" name="'.$orderitems.'" value="'.$orderData->getIncrementId().'">'. $orderData->getIncrementId().'</option>';
    }
    $htmltext=$htmltext."</select>";
    echo $htmltext;exit;
```

Comment: on designerpaidstatus.php what are you returning ? it should return same id with select box

Comment: Hi change designerpaidstatus.php select box id with designerorder_id

Comment: @NishantSaini i changed as you said, now 2nd field `validation` is working, but  for 3rd field `product`,  multiselect box is not displaying any values.

Comment: wait i am check that

Comment: use below code for validation multiple slect box value

Comment: @NishantSaini if we use `dproductselect as id` than only values will display for 3rd field, if we change that , than no values will display.

Comment: function getProductDetail(e)
  {    
    var productId = $("#dproductselect option:selected").attr("class");  
    var finalstrig=productId.split(",");

    var select='';
    select+='<select class="test" multiple="multiple" name="dproduct_ids" id="dproduct_ids">';

    for(i=0;i<finalstrig.length;i++)
    {
      if(finalstrig[i]!=0)
      {
        select +='<option value="'+finalstrig[i]+'">'+finalstrig[i]+'</option>';
      }
    }
    select +='</select>';

Comment: change in this code too $("#dproductselect option:selected"). to $("#designerorder_id option:selected").

Comment: var options = $('#dproduct_ids > option:selected');
         if(options.length == 0){
             alert('no value selected');
             return false;
         }   replace this code with multiple select box validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use this code for multiple selectbox

```js
function multiple1()
{
var options = $('#dproduct_ids > option:selected');
         if(options.length == 0){
             alert('no value selected');
             return false;
         }
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="test" multiple="multiple" name="dproduct_ids" id="dproduct_ids" name="test[]">
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
  </select>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="multiple1()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validate()
{

 var error="";
alert("Test");
 var designer_id = document.getElementById( "designer_id" );
 if( designer_id.value == "" )
 {
   
  error = " Please Select Designer";
  document.getElementById( "error_para1" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }

 var error="";
 var designerorder_id = document.getElementById( "designerorder_id" );
 if( designerorder_id.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Order";
  document.getElementById( "error_para2" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }


 var error="";
 var dproduct_id = document.getElementById( "dproduct_id" );

 if( dproduct_id.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Product";
  document.getElementById( "error_para3" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="update.php" id="" onsubmit="return validate(); ">

        Designer : 
          <select onchange="getOrderDetail(event);" name="designer_id" id="designer_id" required>
            <option value="">Select Designer</option>
                 
          </select>

      Order : 


        <div id="ordernumbers">
          <select name="designerorder_id" id="designerorder_id" required>
            <option>Select Order</option>
          </select>
          </div>      

      Product

        <div id="productnumbers" name="dproduct_id" id="dproduct_id" required>
          <select id="mySelect" >
            <option>Select Products</option>
          </select>

        </div>
  
  <div id="error_para1">Test</div>
  <div id="error_para2"></div>
  <div id="error_para3"></div>

<button type="submit" onclick="validate" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

For the first select you have explicitly set the option value to empty string

```js
function validate()
{

 var error="";

 var designer_id = document.getElementById( "designer_id" );
 if( designer_id.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Designer";
  document.getElementById( "error_para1" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }

 var error="";
 var designerorder_id = document.getElementById( "designerorder_id" );
 if( designerorder_id.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Order";
  document.getElementById( "error_para2" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }


 var error="";
 var dproduct_id = document.getElementById( "dproduct_id" );

 if( dproduct_id.value == "" )
 {
  error = " Please Select Product";
  document.getElementById( "error_para3" ).innerHTML = error;
  return false;
 }
  
  alert("All Good");

}
```

```html
<form >

        Designer : 
          <select  name="designer_id" id="designer_id" required>
            <option value="">Select Designer</option>
                 <option value="1">1</option>
          </select>

      Order : 


        <div id="ordernumbers">
          <select name="designerorder_id" id="designerorder_id" required>
            <option value="">Select Order</option>
             <option value="1">1</option>
          </select>
          </div>      

      Product

        <div id="productnumbers" name="dproduct_id"  required>
          <select id="dproduct_id" >
            <option value="">Select Products</option>
             <option value="1">1</option>
          </select>

        </div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="return validate(); ">Submit</button>
  <div id="error_para1">T</div>
  <div id="error_para2"></div>
  <div id="error_para3"></div>
  </form>
```

whereas for the next ones you haven't done that. 
So the below checks doesn't work

`if( designerorder_id.value == "" )`

`if( dproduct_id.value == "" )`

Comment: can you please tell what code changes  i need to do to get solution for my case ?

Comment: I tried your code, but working only from 1st field dropdown.

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 not able to login.

Comment: sorry, i dont know , for me login is working, thats fine, i got solution, Thanks for your time.....